# How to get the data from json string winform

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Here if this is the string {  "ValidateUser": [    {      "username": "Admin",      "pass": "Admin"    }  ]} than how to get pass value because in pair.value I am only getting username.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(user_db);
        foreach (var i in o["ValidateUser"])
        {
            JObject parsed = JObject.Parse("" + o["ValidateUser"][j]);
            foreach (var pair in parsed)
            {
                if (string.Equals(user_name.Text, pair.Value))
                {
                    if(string.Equals(password.Text,pair.Value))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    }
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: The pasted `JSON` string is not valid.

Comment: How do you expect to read a `ValidateUser` value when the string you posted only contains `username` and `pass` ?

Comment: Sorry this is the json string {  "ValidateUser": [    {      "username": "Admin",      "pass": "Admin"    }  ]}

Comment: In this case, you can parse like - 
`JObject user = JObject.Parse(user_db);
var userName = (string)user["ValidateUser"][0]["username"];
var pass = (string)user["ValidateUser"][0]["pass"];`

Comment: @LJ thanks it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Below code to solve your problem

string source = "{ "ValidateUser": [ { "username": "Admin", "pass":"Admin" } ]}";
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);
Console.WriteLine(data.username);
Console.WriteLine(data.pass);
```

so in case use below code hope that help you.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(user_db);
        foreach (var i in o["ValidateUser"])
        {
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse("" + o["ValidateUser"][j]);
            foreach (var pair in parsed)
            {
                if (string.Equals(user_name.Text, data.username))
                {
                    if(string.Equals(password.Text,data.pass))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Success");
                    }
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This isn't a valid Json string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i knw but its just for example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you could correct it I am not getting from the link you provided!

Comment: @ADMIN no I am not getting any value in data.username